# Windows: Numpy mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, intel

After so many hours of attempts and investigation, I have managed to deal with the `Numpy`s `mkl_intel_thread.dll` file error.
The following may not be the solution for all cases, but I will try to explain the details of my particular case in order to help others with the same problem.

#### MY PROBLEM:

When trying to launch Anaconda's Spyder IDE, it got the following message:

[image: error message]

Investigating I realised that this is a `numpy` problem.

#### MY SETTINGS:

OS: 64-bit Windows 10 Pro

Python Version
[image: Python Version]

Anaconda Version
[image: Anaconda Version]

#### MY SOLUTION:

In this particular case, the following steps worked for me:

● STEP - 1:

I uninstalled Numpy and installed it again with below commands

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

● STEP - 2:

I added the following to the PATH system variable:

```
%IFORT_COMPILER15%\redist\ia32\mkl
%IFORT_COMPILER15%\redist\intel64\mkl
```

With reference to [software.intel.com](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/542583)

(I personally think that in this case this step doesn't have much to do. But I mention it anyway because I don't want to skip any detail.)

● STEP - 3:

Then, I went to: `{Anaconda directory}\pkgs\numpy-{Version}\info\test`

In my case:

```
Anaconda directory= C:\Users\Ferdinand\Anaconda3
Version = 1.15.4-py37h19fb1c0_0
```

Run the file `run_test.py` located there.

[image: file location]

[image: file content]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

Now the problem is solved. As I said before, it might not be the ultimate solution, but in my case it worked.

I hope someday this helps someone to solve this problem.

Comment: Your post contained both problem and its solution. Its really appreciated that you want help others, but do it in right way by adding the solution at answer section instead of question section.

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Comment: this solved my problem, thank you