# Running python script via Pentaho

Tags: python, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm running into trouble trying to run a python script using Pentaho. I have a test script that reads in a csv, adds a new column, then writes out a new csv to my target directory.

I'm using the "shell" job under the "scripting" drop down.
I checked the "insert script" option on the "General" tab and inserted this

```
"C:\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe" 
"C:\Users\mike\Documents\mike\Pentaho_Test_Aug16.py"
```

into the "Script" tab.

When I run sys.executable in spyder I get this and that's what I'm using for my python.exe location

```
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe'
```

When I run the process in Pentaho, it returns this in the log file:

```
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Spoon - Starting job...
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Pentaho Test with Python - Start of job execution
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Pentaho Test with Python - Starting entry [Shell]
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - Running on platform : Windows Server 2016
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - Executing command : cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\MICHAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\19\kettle_9d3125e0-febd-11eb-aa51-37d1ddb117e6shell.bat"
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - (stdout)
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - (stdout) C:\data-integration>"C:\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users\mike\Documents\mike\Pentaho_Test_Aug16.py"
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:140: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)   from . import _distributor_init
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) Traceback (most recent call last):
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)   File "C:\Users\mike\Documents\mike\Pentaho_Test_Aug16.py", line 2, in <module>
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)     import pandas as pd
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)     "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) numpy:
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) - Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) - If you have already done that, then:
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)   1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe",
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)      and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)      interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)   2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)      https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)      - how you installed Python
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)      - how you installed numpy
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)      - your operating system
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)      - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)      - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) - If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)   (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr) Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Shell - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : (stderr)
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Pentaho Test with Python - Finished job entry [Shell] (result=[false])
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Pentaho Test with Python - Job execution finished
2021/08/16 14:13:10 - Spoon - Job has ended.
2021/08/16 14:13:31 - Spoon - Spoon
2021/08/16 14:13:48 - Spoon - Spoon
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, this code works when I run it in Spyder but fails when I try to run it via Pentaho.

In case you want an example of what I'm trying to do, this guy at youtube is doing what I want. I based my approach off of what he did.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sN-MNRitfrA

No ideas? Anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

Following Dirk's advice below, I added the command to append the location of the necessary mlk_... files to the system PATH variable. Entering the following into the "Execute a shell script..." dialog solved my problem:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin
"C:\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe" 
"C:\Users\mike\Documents\mike\Pentaho_Test_Aug16.py"
```

Comment: the last two lines on the error output tell you what's going on, it couldn't find a dll. I looked around a little bit and it seems that numpy needs a dll that probably resides in the Anaconda library subfolder. At least one person was able to get it working by copying that dll to the numpy\core subfolder. That was for Anaconda2, so the folder structure may look a bit different for Anaconda3, I don't have either available right now. But essentially find out which dlls numpy needs and make sure they are available, either by copying them or by extending your PATH env variable.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I am no longer getting the same error so I think I'm making progress. The remaining problem is >> INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. mkl_intel_thread.dll. Shell - (stdout) Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll<<< I can see it in the folder with all the other MKL files so I don't know what's going on. Reading up on it now; I've tried a couple proposed solutions but no luck

Comment: this guy here seems to have had the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919580/windows-numpy-mkl-intel-thread-dll